# google cloud dataflow - can I get "event-time" from meta-data?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

greeting developers,
I know dataflow(DF) can get event-time from I/O (like Pubsub), and I can also assign "event-time" to data. But, can I get this attribute value from data?
 
For my understanding, I can get input timestamp(processing-time) from data, but not event-time.

#### Q1: Can I get event-time from data ?

#### Q2: If I can, how to get it ?

thanks for your helping :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the timestamp of an element in a DoFn, you can call [ProcessContext.timestamp()](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/DoFn.ProcessContext.html#method-detail).  To set the timestamp of an element according to your  own application logic, you can use [Context.outputWithTimestamp()](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/DoFn.Context#method-detail).

Like so:

```
@Override
public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
  // Generate a timestamp that falls somewhere in two hours after the event time.
  long randMillis = (long) (Math.random() * Duration.standardHours(2).getMillis());
  Instant randomTimestamp = c.timestamp().plus(randMillis);
  c.outputWithTimestamp(c.element(), new Instant(randomTimestamp));
}
```

Comment: I know how to assign timestamp to data, and how to get "input-time"(processing time) from the data. but the problem I want to ask is how to get "event-time" from the data?

Comment: Yes, you can use ProcessContext.timestamp() for that.  Unless I'm misunderstanding your question?

Comment: `c.timestamp()` returns the timestamp (in event time) assigned to the current element. At a source (such as PubSub) this is assigned either from a timestamp attribute in the message, or based on the arrival time of that input (other sources may have other semantics). Within a pipeline you can use `outputWithTimestamp` to change the timestamp assigned to the element.  If you don't use `outputWithTimestamp` the timestamp assigned by the source propagates.

If that doesn't clarify could you elaborate on your problem with an example or more details?

Comment: Recently, I figure out ProcessContext.timestamp() is represent event-time, I think is processing-time before. For your helping, I know ProcessContext.timestamp() can get the result I want. Thanks for your helps :D